# UNUserNotification not visually showing notification on real device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, notifications

My notification works fine on simulator but on my device (running iOS 10.3.3) the notification does not show at all (phone locked at time of trigger) but the phone does vibrate when triggered and the app does get updated to correct settings so I know that the notification is getting triggered - its just not visually showing on the device. Have I missed anything?

This is where I setup authorisation for notifications in AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    locationManager.delegate = self

    // Setup notifications authorization request
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
        // Check if granted, if not then notify user
        if granted {
            print("Notification access granted")
        } else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "General Error: notification access not granted")
            self.window?.rootViewController?.showAlertApplicationSettings(forErorType: .turnOnNotifications)
        }
    }
```

Location trigger in AppDelegate:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    if region is CLCircularRegion {
        print("DidEnter: \(region.identifier)")
        handleEvent(forRegion: region)
    }
}
```

Handle event code that gets data from core data and then send to notifyUser method in AppDelegate:

```
func handleEvent(forRegion region: CLRegion) {
    guard let reminder = getReminder(fromRegionIdentifier: region.identifier) else {
        // There was a problem access the notification data, inform user
        notifyUser(title: "Reminder notifiction error", subtitle: "One of your notifications has just been triggered but error restriving notification data", notes: nil)
        return
    }

    notifyUser(title: reminder.titleString, subtitle: "Reminder has been triggered", notes: reminder.notesString)
    updateRemindersState(reminder: reminder)
}
```

This is the actual notification trigger code in AppDelegate:

```
func notifyUser(title: String, subtitle: String, notes: String?) {
    // show an alert if applocation is active
    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
        window?.rootViewController?.showAlert(title: title, message: subtitle)
    } else {
        let notification = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        notification.title = title
        notification.subtitle = subtitle
        if let notes = notes {
            notification.body = notes
        }
        notification.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "Notification", content: notification, trigger: nil)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

p.s. checked that on my device in settings its has Show in Notifications Centre, sounds, show on lock screen, banners all turned on.

Comment: Something I've noticed (don't know if this is gonna help you): you need to add to `requestAthorization` in `granted` case the following: `center.delegate = self`. Apple documentation quote: 

`IMPORTANT


You must assign your delegate to the shared UNUserNotificationCenter object before your app or app extension finishes launching. Failure to do so may prevent your app from handling notifications correctly.` ; [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html)

Comment: Thanks, You might be onto something. Will have to try some things out to see if this is the case.

Comment: Did you find an answer? Having a similar issue - works on sim but not on phone